# Could anybody identify this plant for me?

Tags: identification, leafy-vegetables

![Hi 
I found this big leafed plant growing out of a bucket that I had planted pumpkins, so I'm not sure if this is the pumpkin or a invader plant.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhyQ9.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not a pumpkin. My bets are on something similar to *Erigeron annuus*, a weed: daisy like flowers, but smaller flowers (in a larger plant). It produces a lot of small flowers, so a lot of seeds.

Check in Google for various photo, and look if there were similar plants around your pumpikn.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like *Plantago* ([plantains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantago) or fleaworts), it is a very common plant in Europe where I live. I am not sure about South Africa, though.

Comment: I'd say it's definitely a plaintain, based on the buds coming through the center of the basal leaves. The leaves look a little ruffle-ier than the variety I'm used to killing in the US.

Comment: In effect, Erigeron doen't have so many parallel veins. OTOH the colour and habit do not look like Plantago I know. (but on seedling pot, they can grow much more).